# Unable to get dynamic database name in gulp tasks

Tags: node.js, mongodb, gulp

I am new to gulp

I have to run multiple services along with separate database connections.While start the service, I want to load default data into respective database.

So, I tried to pass database name dynamically with environment variables, but it's getting undefined.

When I give database name statically, it's working fine.

Here is what I am tried, please check and give me some direction to fix this.

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var nodemon = require('gulp-nodemon');
var run = require('gulp-run-command').default;
var argv = require('yargs').argv; 

gulp.task('env', function(done) {
 if (argv.dev) {
   process.env.argv = 'Dev'
 } else if (argv.prod) {
   process.env.argv = 'Prod'
 } else {
   process.env.argv = 'Dev'
 }
 require('./config/config');
 done() 
  console.log(process.env.DB_Name) // displaying data base name
})

gulp.task('default_tabs', run('mongorestore --db 
  '+process.env.DB_Name+' ./tables'), function(done) {  
  done()
 })

gulp.task('default', gulp.series('env', 'default_tabs',function(done){
 nodemon({
  script: 'userProfileService.js'
 })
 done()
}))
```

Comment: make sure the single quotation mark after ```mongorestore --db``` is on the same line as it.

Comment: Hi dotconnor, I didn't understand your comment, can you elaborate it please.